# Is it possible to transfer an object with dataTransfer

Tags: javascript, dom-events, data-transfer

I have an `<img>` element that has a custom property `meta`, which in turn has its own properties.  When dragging the image I would like to set the `dataTransfer`, of the event, to contain the `meta` object itself and not have to set multiple references to the `meta` properties.  Hope that makes sense?  Example follows...

p.s.  I'm using Chrome, I believe I read somewhere that this might have issues with `dataTransfer`.

### Current Working Usage:

```
img=div.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
img.meta={
    tit:itm.tit,
    ref:itm.ref,
    cat:itm.cat
};
img.addEventListener('dragstart',function(e){
    e.dataTransfer.setData('tit',this.meta.tit);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('ref',this.meta.ref);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('catId',this.meta.cat.id);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('catRef',this.meta.cat.ref);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('url',this.src);
});
enGal.appendChild(img);
```

This is viable but just means I have to call each reference, from the `drop`  event, to get the data i.e.:

```
title=e.dataTransfer.getData('tit');
...
```

I would prefer to be able to do something like this:

```
img=div.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
img.meta={
    tit:itm.tit,
    ref:itm.ref,
    cat:itm.cat,
    // EDIT
    url:img.src
};
img.addEventListener('dragstart',function(e){
    // EDIT
    e.dataTransfer.setData('meta',this.meta);
});
enGal.appendChild(img);
```

Then:

```
meta=e.dataTransfer.getData('meta');
title=meta.tit;
...
```

If I try to set `dataTransfer` to the `meta` object, it simply returns the object as a string i.e.:

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('meta',this.meta);

meta=e.dataTransfer.getData('meta');

// meta == "[object Object]"

console.log(meta); // "[object Object]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use JSON to pass the meta object since:

```
    img=div.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    img.meta={
        tit:itm.tit,
        ref:itm.ref,
        cat:itm.cat,
        // EDIT
        url:img.src
    };
    img.addEventListener('dragstart',function(e){
        // EDIT
        e.dataTransfer.setData('meta',JSON.stringify(this.meta));
//converting to JSON in the line above.
    });
    enGal.appendChild(img);


    //converting from JSON to object
    meta=JSON.parse(e.dataTransfer.getData('meta'));
```

Comment: Interesting... Never thought 'bout that! cheers. tho could still do with knowing if it's possible to pass an  object literal?